# Create a constantly running method

Tags: react-native, reactjs

I would like to create a method that monitors the current time using momentjs and will execute `this.setState()` in a specific time, in react native.

I had no problems getting the current time, the problem is, that i need some kind of a method that will constantly run in the background and execute the task.

Something like angular's `$scope.watch` for you guys that are familiar with angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an interval after the component is mounted:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    //your logic here
    this.setState({})
  }, 300)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval

```
componentDidMount() {
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
     this.setTime({
        time: //moment time
    }
});
}
```